# Finding all the analyitical function in the unit annulus that satisfy a given condition for natural numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Let $f$ be an analytic function in the annulus $0 < |z| < 1 $ such that it's singularity in $z=0$ is not essential. I want to find all of such functions $f$ that satisfy for $n = 3, 4,...$:

1. $f(\frac 1n)=\frac {n^4}{1+n}$
2. $f(\frac 1n)=\frac {\sqrt{n^2-4}}{2n}$
3. $f(\frac 1n)=\frac 1{2^n}$

I'm pretty clueless on how to even start.
I thought using the fact that $z^mf(z)$ is analytic in the unit disk, and then try to satisfy the conditions, but I still couldnt understand how to do that.
Could you please give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** As you said there exists a $m$ so that $g(z)=z^mf(z)$ is Analytic. Moreover, as $f$ is not continuous at $z=0$, the singularity is not removable, hence it must be a pole. Therefore, we can pick the $m$ in such a way that $g(0) \neq 0$.

As
$$g(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{n^m}\frac {n^4}{1+n}$$
and $\lim_n g(\frac{1}{n}) =g(0) \neq 0$ it follows that $m=3$ and

$$g(\frac{1}{n})=\frac {n}{1+n}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}$$

Therefore the Analityc functions $g(z)$ and $\frac{1}{1+z}$ are equal on the sequence $\frac{1}{n}$.

**2.** **Hint** $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{4}{n^2}}}{2}$ has a finite limit at $z=0$. Deduce that the singularity is removable (same way as in 1: if there is a pole, by multiplying by the right $z^m$ you get an Analytic function with a non-zero limit).

**3.** Same as $2$, prove that $f$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$, and that $f(0)=0$.

Let $m$ be the order of the zero at $z=0$. What can you say then about 
$$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{f(z)}{z^m}$$

what happens when you calculate the limit along $z =\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: I still dont understand how I should proceed... 

The result you presented in (1) for example, is that those functions are those that are analytic in the annulus, have pole at 0 from order 3 and coincide with $\frac{z^3}{1+z} on the series $1/n$? 

How do I conclude what kind of functions are those?

Comment: Ohhh I get it now! we use the uniqeness of an analytic g in that region, Thanks!!